# Best way to use DllImport in C# and How to get control back from external method

Tags: c#, interop, dllimport, unmanaged, windows

I am calling an external method in my C# desktop application

```
[DllImport(CONST_DLL_PATH)]
internal static extern bool ProcessXML(string inputPath, string outputPath);
```

I have few questions:

1. How important is to specify EntryPoint or any other attribute for DllImport?
2. What if ProcessXML fails, how to get program execution control back from external method?
3. What are the alternatives of DllImport?

I want to make sure in case of failure of ProcessXML, control should be returned to application.

Comment: If you want to be sure that this native code doesn't kill your program then **don't** pinvoke it.  The only way to be sure is to run it in another process.  Given the signature of this function, there isn't any point in making it complicated.  Process.Start() is all you need.

Comment: How to call a method of an external dll using `Process.Start()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) If the method name is different from the DLL's entry's name - you'll have to specify that in the `EntryPoint` property. Otherwise, you may omit it.

2) Control is returned to you after that method's execution ends. How it handles errors is depend on its implementation, but usually methods returns an error code (in this case, probably `true` if the execution succeeded, and `false` if it failed). Once again, it depends on its implementation, but it may set the Win32's "LastError". If it does, you should set the property `SetLastError` of the `DllImport` attribute, and if it fails, you may call to `Marshal.GetLastError()`, or throw `Win32Exception`.

3) DllImport allows you to consume a method from an unmanaged DLL. You can also wrap it with C++/CLI project, to create managed DLL wrapper, but on most cases that would be an over-kill.